# how to pass the checked values of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/120/)

I have a button add which when clicked adds input datas to a new row as given in the screenshot.The group button is used for creating a group of user numbers.Suppose I want to create a group **friends** which will contains mobile numbers of 1st row,2nd row and last row. So for this I will just select the checkboxes of 1st row,2nd row and the last row.Then after pressing the group button it will create a group.Group name along with group members(mobile numbers) should be stored in database.So i am using ajax.Please tell me how to pass mobile numbers of selected rows.
[image]
following is the jquery

```
var val=0;
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#btn1').click(function(){
      if($(".span4").val()!="")
      {
  $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr'+val+'"></tr>');
  $("#mytr"+val).append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr'+val+'" checked ></td>');
  
             $(".span4").each(function () {
            
             $("#mytr"+val).append("<td >"+$(this).val()+"</td>");
                
              });
              val++;
      }
      else
      {
          alert("please fill the form completely");
      }
              });
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        var creat_group=confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
        if(val>1){
           alert(creat_group);
            
                 
              }
    });
          

});
```

**What is group and why do i want it?**
Suppose if i have some 100 records,out of that some are **java** employee,some are **.net** employee and some are **mainframe**
Suppose if i want to send sms only to java employee,if i am not having group then out of 100 records
I have to manually check who are java employees.So in order to avoid that I want to create groups 1 for java,1 for .net and another for mainframe.So in order to send sms to only java people I can select the java group and send sms

Comment: what backend (server-side language) would you be using for the ajax ?

Comment: @aleation jsp/servlet

Comment: i'm writting something for you just hold on a few mins xD, basicly you need to declare a variable(array), find the checked checkboxes, and push the info into that var, then send it to your server via ajax

Comment: @aleation sure i amwaiting

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var obj={};// add this
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
        $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
        $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
        $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" checked ></td>');
        $(".span4").each(function () {
            $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
        });
        // add below code
        var arr={};
        name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
        email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
        mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
        arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
        obj[val]=arr;
        // add upto above line
        val++;
    } else {
        alert("please fill the form completely");
    }
});
```

Also Update and add **below code**,

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
    var creat_group = confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
    if (creat_group) {
        console.log(obj);
    }        
});

// to get the checked data only
$(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
    if(!this.checked)
    {
        key=$(this).attr('name').replace('mytr','');
        obj[key]=null;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kfek/3/)

Comment: thanks for answering,in ajax for passing values we write **$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { toNumber: number, body: msg},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert(data);                  
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR){
                        alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                    }
                });** in your case how to do?

Comment: @javaBeginner pass **data:obj** in `$.ajax`

Comment: in ajax to retrieve we use request.getparameter(name) to get the value.So in this case how?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751118/output-json-array-in-a-html-tablea-jsp-page

Comment: isn't calling `find()` for each cell a bit overkill? I'm not questioning you just asking, as I'm not a jQuery expert xD

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment here's my answer, you need to add that to your `$('#btn2').click()`:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aleation/bTAxe/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        var checkedRows = $('#mytable').find("input:checked").parent().parent();
        var total = checkedRows.length;
        var info = [];
        for(i = 0; i < total; i++){
            var row = $(checkedRows[i]).children();
            var tmpInfo = [];
                tmpInfo["name"]= row[1].innerHTML;
                tmpInfo["email"]= row[2].innerHTML;
                tmpInfo["phone"]= row[3].innerHTML;
            info.push(tmpInfo);
        }

        console.log(info);

        $.post('yourpage', info, function(){
            //on success code, can be an alert or anything you want.
        });
    });
});
```

**Explanation**: Basicly we first find all the checked checkboxes parent row and create an array (`checkedRows`);

Then we loop through this array (it's much quicker than using `$.each`) and add the table cell 1 2 and 3's inner HTML to the `info` array. (td 0 is the checkbox's cell so we don't need it);

Send info to your server, it should be an array of n sub-arrays (depending on how many rows were checked), the sub-arrays will be holding the name, email and phone.

Comment: of course not, I don't have access to your server, see the console log or combine it with your code and test.

Comment: It's not, I just checked, it's returning an array object