# json print into html java

Tags: java, html, spark-java

I am trying to find a way to display readable JSON in html. Im using Gson to get the JSON into a readable string format and the console output is as follows:

```
{
"select_clause": {
  "Columns": [
    {
      "column": "a",
      "alias": ""
    }
  ]
},
"from_clause": {
  "Tables": [
    {
      "alias": "",
      "table": "b"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

But when I try to append that into a StringBuilder html I get:

```
{ "select_clause": { "Columns": [ { "column": "a", "alias": "" } ] }, "from_clause": { "Tables": [ { "alias": "", "table": "b" } ] } }
```

Is there anyway to make this show up in html as it does in the console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751118/output-json-array-in-a-html-tablea-jsp-page

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript