# How to display JSON List in JSP page?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

**How to display JSON List in JSP page using loop**

what would be the javascript loop for that JSON

```js
[0:{id: 8, book_name: "sasdas", book_author: "asdas", book_price: 66}
1:{id: 9, book_name: "abhishek", book_author: "asd", book_price: 49898}
2:{id: 10, book_name: "dasd", book_author: "asa", book_price: 2121}]
```

Comment: What did you try up to now on your own?

Comment: Display how? Table? Just String? Anyways, if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751253/9192223

Comment: I want to display it in tabular form